# Flash .swf file is not working on web server, but it's working fine on localhost

Tags: flash

.swf file not working when after I upload it to web server, but works just fine when opening on localhost or standalone .swf file. I tried 3 different servers, same result.

Any idea would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I also get "Movie not loaded..." on right click on swf

Comment: have you checked the path to the .swf file (is it relative or absolute, is the path to it correct in both cases (local and server)) ? is this main .swf loading another .swf ? Can you access the .swf file directly on the server(without it being wrapped in an html page) ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to view it in Internet Explorer on the Server or as a client?  If your viewing on the Server itself, Check the Enhanced Security Settings are enabled or not, if its a client, obviously see if flash is enabled.

If All are ok, then file pathway and/or firewall settings for content need to be checked..

Comment: I tried it from http://website.com/path/to/file.swf, nothing. Again, I tried other swf on these servers and they are working. I disabled firewall, still nothing. I moved the file locally inside an empty folder (on desktop) and it's working, so I don't think it's a pathway problem. I'm not sure what "Check the Enhanced Security Settings" means. It also flashes a black color for a millisecond, and then white.. nothing

Answer (score 0):

'I tried it from website.com/path/to/file.swf, nothing.' - what means nothing ? did you get some server error like "404 Not Found" or just 'Movie not loaded...' ?
try with different browsers with/without plugins

Answer (score 0):

Which webserver you are using? If its IIS then you need to check whether .swf is added in MIME Types of that site.